# Navigation Experimental: NavigationHeader scroll with content

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to implement [scroll-then-fix](https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/) using NavigationExperimental. (Medium android app implements this.)

First I need to make NavigationHeader scroll with the content instead of fixed at the top. And the Navigation fixed at the top when scrolling to certain position.

My first attempt is let NavigationHeader listen to the scroll event of the NavigationCard, here's the problem:

How do NavigationHeader/NavigationCard communicate each other? NavigationHeader needs to know the scroll position of the NavigationCard to change the state. But they are two separate components.

Or maybe there's an smarter way doing this? Thanks for your help!